# Какой синоним можно подобрать к сочетанию ТОЛЬКО СЕЙЧАС?

Tags: синонимы

Какой синоним можно подобрать к сочетанию "ТОЛЬКО СЕЙЧАС" в предложении "Василий вернулся со службы еще год назад, а я об этом узнал только сейчас"?

Comment: Посмотрите в словарях синонимов, это так просто!

Comment: а в данном случае "только" является ограничительной или выделительной частицей?

Comment: Было бы чего ограничивать, являлась бы ограничительной.